# How to set two different pip versions for Python 2.7 and Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

At the moment, it appears my `pip` is the pip for Python 3.4

I would like this version of pip to be used for Python 2.7, and the Python 3.4 version of pip to be `pip3`.

How can I do this? I tried installing both with Macports....

EDIT: In `/opt/local/bin` I have `pip`, `pip-2.7`, and `pip-3.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have a Mac to test this on, but I think it may work.

First, find the path of your `pip` and `pip3` executable. From the terminal run `which pip` and `which pip3`.

Once you have the path open the file. The first line should be something like: `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4`

Try changing the version from `3.4` to `2.7`.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't have `python` in `/usr/local/share/`

Comment: I edited my answer to include finding where `pip` and `pip3` are called from. Let me know if that works

Comment: That works! Now, how do I set up `pip3`? Currently, it does not exist, even though `pip-3.4` is installed.

Comment: Hmm, your installation is a bit different then what I typically see. Can you try to remove python3 and reinstall from the official python osx download page? I know for fact that download includes `pip3` https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

Comment: It may be best to simply uninstall pip-3.4 and retry. Thanks!